# Python Not able to append new line character after the end of a line when writing to a new file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

In below method I am sorting the contents of the file according to timestamp , and it's working fine also
But I don't know how to append new line when I am writing to a newly made file.It is writing in the same line I want to change the lines in my output file as input is very large I need to use chunk in this case
so using readlines or storing in any data structure will won't work here

1)My **Input file format** is as below

```
TIME[04.26_12:30:30:853664]  ID[ROLL:201987623]  MARKS[PHY:100|MATH:200|CHEM:400]
TIME[03.27_12:29:30.553669]  ID[ROLL:201987623]  MARKS[PHY:100|MATH:1200|CHEM:900]
TIME[03.26_12:28:30.753664]  ID[ROLL:2341987623] MARKS[PHY:100|MATH:200|CHEM:400]
TIME[03.26_12:29:30.853664]  ID[ROLL:201978623]  MARKS[PHY:0|MATH:0|CHEM:40]
TIME[04.27_12:29:30.553664]  ID[ROLL:2034287623] MARKS[PHY:100|MATH:200|CHEM:400]
```

Code is as below

```
import re
from functools import partial
from itertools import groupby
from typing import Tuple

regex = re.compile(r"^.*TIME\[([^]]+)\]ID\[ROLL:([^]]+)\].+$")
def func1(arg) -> bool:
    return regex.match(arg)


def func2(arg) -> Tuple[str, int]:
    match = regex.match(arg)
    if match:
        return match.group(1), int(match.group(2))
    return "", 0

def func3(arg) -> int:
    match = regex.match(arg)
    if match:
        return int(match.group(2))
    return 0

def read_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size=1024*1024):
    while True:
        data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data

with open('b.txt') as fr:
    for chunk in read_in_chunks(fr):
        collection = filter(func1, chunk.splitlines())
        collection = sorted(collection, key=func2)
        for key, group in groupby(collection, key=func3):
            with open(f"ROLL_{key}", mode="wa") as fw:
                fw.writelines(group)# want suggestions to append newline character before every line
```

2)Actual Output what I am getting now

In file name ROLL_201987623.txt

```
 TIME[03.27_12:29:30.553669]  ID[ROLL:201987623]  MARKS[PHY:100|MATH:1200|CHEM:900]  TIME[04.26_12:30:30:853664]  ID[ROLL:201987623]  MARKS[PHY:100|MATH:200|CHEM:400]
```

3)Desired Output (I want to change the line as given in input format)

```
 TIME[03.27_12:29:30.553669]  ID[ROLL:201987623]  MARKS[PHY:100|MATH:1200|CHEM:900]  
 TIME[04.26_12:30:30:853664]  ID[ROLL:201987623]  MARKS[PHY:100|MATH:200|CHEM:400]
```

Currently I am getting the output in the same line that is the main problem for me ?

Comment: What about `line + '\n'`?

Comment: you are trying to say  'fw.writelines(group+'\n')'?

Comment: it's giving error @snakecharmerb  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'itertools._grouper' and 'str'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
#  suggestions to append newline character before every line
group = map(lambda x: x + '\n', group)
fw.writelines(group)
```

Comment: Your answer will work, however it's generally recommended to use list comprehension rather than the map/lambda function in python.

Comment: `group = [x + '\n' for x in group]` you mean @mousetail ?

Comment: Yes, that would do the same thing is a bit more "pythony" way

Answer (score 1):

The `writelines()` function, despite its name, will not actually add a newline character to each line. (this is done to correspond with `.readlines()` function that will not remove the \ `\n` in the file.

I would suggest using `fw.writelines([i+'\n' for i in group])` to manually add the necessary line breaks.